# Can someone explains me about Liquid Network

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, bitcoin-wallet-app, liquid

I'm trying to integrate liquid network with my node.js application. Such that i want to create liquid wallet address, send a transaction from 1:1 on liquid network and check balance for that wallet address.

The only useful thing i found was to use bitfnex or other exchanges but they don't allow to create wallet addresses just deposit addresses.

So anyone can guide me regarding this, Do i need my own node for this and how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [elementsd](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/releases) with below elements.conf:

```
chain=elementsregtest

rpcport = 18884
rpcuser = user1
rpcpassword = password1
```

Use the example mentioned in [Elements code tutorial](https://elementsproject.org/elements-code-tutorial/other-languages#nodejs):

```
const request = require('request');

let username = "user1";
let password = "password1";

let options = {
    url: "http://localhost:18884",
    method: "post",
    headers:
    { 
     "content-type": "text/plain"
    },
    auth: {
        user: username,
        pass: password
    },
    body: JSON.stringify( {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "rpctest", "method": "getwalletinfo", "params": [] })
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred: ', error);
    } else {
        json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json.result.balance.bitcoin);
    }
});
```

The output will show the bitcoin balance returned by [`getwalletinfo`](https://elementsproject.org/en/doc/0.18.1.11/rpc/wallet/getwalletinfo/).

Other RPCs: https://elementsproject.org/en/doc/0.18.1.11/rpc/

https://docs.blockstream.com/liquid/developer-guide/developer-guide-index.html?highlight=rpc#basic-commands